# Is "femenina" the female equivalent of the English/Spanish word "macho"?

Tags: traducción, adjetivos, género

The *OED* defines the English word "[macho](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/111869)" as

> a notably or ostentatiously masculine, tough, or vigorous man; one who is aggressively proud of his masculinity.

¿Is "*[femenina](https://dle.rae.es/?w=femenino)*" the female equivalent of "*[macho](https://dle.rae.es/?w=macho)*", where "*femenina*" would be

> a notably or ostentatiously feminine, tough, or vigorous woman; one who is aggressively proud of her femininity.

Answer (score 2):

A male animal is a "macho" and a female is a "hembra".

Una ardilla macho (a male squirrel). Un pájaro carpintero hembra (a female woodpecker).

Comment: In addition, it should be noted that many spanish speakers use the word "macho" to describe a human,  but it carries a connotation of not only masculine, but also like an animal.  Hence the idea of exagerated masculinity.